# Directly extend an HTML Element with a custom method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to attach a function onto a specific html element so that if later on I pull up that element with a `querySelector` I can run that function as a method on that element.

```
interface Foo extends HTMLDivElement {
    showBar: Function;
};

function createFooBar(node: HTMLElement) {
    const foo = document.createElement('div');
    foo.classList.add('foo');
    const bar = document.createElement('div');
    bar.classList.add('bar');
    bar.style = "display: none;";
    node.appendChild(foo);
    node.appendChild(bar);

    //Here I want to add a function to the element
    foo.showBar = (thing: string) => {
        bar.innerText = thing;
        bar.style = "";
    };
}

for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    createFooBar(document.querySelector('body'));
}

const foos: NodeListOf<Foo> = document.querySelectorAll('.foo');
for (let i=0; i<foos.length; i++) {
    foos[i].showBar(i.toString());
}
```

In this code each instance of bar is connected to an instance of foo during the createFooBar function. When `foo.showBar(thing)` is called later it knows which bar to show for each foo. In my code editor I get the following error:

```
TS2339: Property 'showBar' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'
```

Makes sense. This pushes me in the direction of creating a `class` for this type of element that has `showBar()` as a method. From the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html) it seems like it's doable to make a custom element, but I can't help but feel like this is unnecessary and that there ought to be some way to attach a function to elements like one would when using `addEventListener`.

Is there a way to attach a function to an html element in the DOM without creating a custom html element?

Comment: This is really a set of "events" that you handle with code such as a function which you can learn about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: Now that you have read that, explore some of the events available that you can handle https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: To dig deeper, explore the various actual specifications here https://www.w3.org or the HTML https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/ or https://www.w3.org/standards/ and the EMCA standard which JavaScript is based upon (Typescript is based on that) https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#Title and the JavaScript language resources https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Language_Resources  and then Microsoft's TypeScript related https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html

Comment: I've got an event handler on a separate input element which I want to call a recursive function on a set of div elements. It's this recursive function that I want to bind to the div elements. So as far as I understand the addEventHandler won't help because the event isn't happening on the divs that I'm interested in. Is it possible to create a sort of sudo event that the first event handler fires in the div elements?

Comment: You can attach events including a custom event you define https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent like the "cat" example in the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent